# How to update the value of a field dependant upon the the fields ID in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am looking to create links to website pages and to automate the procedure a bit more I would like to have a standard link followed by the ID of each field.

For example, I would like the standard link to be 'www.google.com'. I would then like to update the "Link" field dependant upon the ID of that attribute. For example, attribute 001 would become 'www.google.com/001'.

I was hoping to do this using a simple expression within the field calculator of QGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
'www.google.com/' || "ID_column"
```